# How can I make Dr John mention Marie Laveau?

Tags: gabriel-knight

I am currently playing Gabriel Knight: Sins of the Fathers for the first time. I have checked walkthroughs on a few occasions when I haven't made progress for a bit.

The walkthroughs suggest that if I ask Dr John (in the Voodoo museum) about Historical Voodoo enough then he will mention Marie Laveau. However, I have asked him about Historical Voodoo many times and he is now just saying "I've given you as much detail as I can...". He hasn't mentioned Marie and she has not appeared as a dialog option as she should.

I have started a fresh game and played just enough to get to talk to Dr John and ask him about Historical Voodoo. In this case he did mention Marie and she is now a dialog option for me. But I don't really want to replay everything to get where I am up to.

**Is there anything I can do to make Marie Laveau a dialog option?**
Or perhaps:
**what action might have caused this behaviour?** (so I might be able to load a saved game from before I did that.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After I finished the game (by playing through afresh) I went back to see if I could find the point where this situation occurs. My theory was that because I had gone to the graveyard and inspected Marie's tomb before meeting Dr John that was maybe the reason he wasn't mentioning her. However I wasn't able to make this situation occur again. **So it might just have been a once-off, or just a very specific set of circumstances...**

I reloaded my original game (where I couldn't make Marie the dialog option appear) and I was able to get up to Day 9 (before I went to bed) so I'm sure **I could finish the game without the Marie Laveau dialog option**.